# What will kafka respond if I use features that kafka-jms-client doesn't support?

Tags: apache-kafka, jms, confluent-platform

I want to use kafka-jms-client to replace my current jms broker. According to the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/kafka-jms-client/index.html), some features are not supported, such as commit or rollback. What will happen when the client calls a commit or rollback? Does that API simply respond OK but doesn’t actually do anything on the Kafka side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A peek at the source code reveals that the implementations both `javax.jms.Session.commit()` and `javax.jms.Session.rollback()` for the Kafka JMS client do nothing.

[Here's](https://github.com/adispennette/apache-kafka-jms/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/jms/KafkaJmsSession.java#L154) the implementation for `rollback()`, and [here's](https://github.com/adispennette/apache-kafka-jms/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/jms/KafkaJmsSession.java#L146) the implementation for `commit()` (which invokes [`commit()` on `KafkaMessageConsumer`](https://github.com/adispennette/apache-kafka-jms/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/jms/KafkaMessageConsumer.java#L141)). As you can see both methods ultimately do nothing. They'll just return as if everything worked.

Lot's of other methods on the `javax.jms.Session` implementation follow this same pattern.